# Github blocks pushes even from the allowed address. How can I fix it?

Tags: git, email, github, settings

Github blocks pushes even from the allowed address. How can I fix it?

I went to `http://github.com/settings/emails`, checked both the `Keep my email addresses private` and the `Block command line pushes that expose my email`.

I went to my git bash and wrote the following: `git config --global user.email "1234567+mynickname@users.noreply.github.com"`. Instead of the `1234567+mynickname` I put actual values from the settings.

[image]

Now I try to push and I am getting the following error:

> Can't push refs to remote. Try running 'Pull' first to integrate your changes.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. I guess it will be extremely useful for some people, because one can spent enormous amount of time trying to fix it.

The problem was that my local repo contained a commit, which was not on the GitHub. Now whenever I would try to push my local repo to GitHub that commit would be pushed.

But the commit itself already had the email, so changing the config in git bash was not going to help, because it would not affect the commit with a prohibited email in any way.

**TL;DR** Disable the email privacy on GitHub side, push changes. Then change email to the allowed locally. Then enable the privacy setting on GitHub side. And from now on all commits will work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

The remote branch has commits that your local branch doesn't. You could `fetch` the remote changes, `rebase` your local changes and then try to `push`.